# How do you configure TeamCity as a subdomain under Plesk and IIS?

Tags: subdomain, iis, plesk, configuration

Today I bought a domain and a VPS. The VPS came with Plesk installed. I added my website (`example.com`) and a subdomain (`ci.example.com`) to Plesk and IIS.

When I disable example.com from Plesk panel, I can access the website through IIS (correctly).

The problem is that I can't access TeamCity (an application) with my `ci.example.com` subdomain even though I followed [these instructions](http://blogs.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-teamcity-in-iis-7/). When D try to access `ci.example.com` it's showing the Plesk default page even when it's disabled in Plesk panel.

If I add `ci.example.com` to IIS as website, I'm getting 403.1 error (the default IIS error when a website is empty.)

How do I configure this properly?